# How to write an anchor element of html within a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, anchor

I have to make a Javascript array in which one of the elements is:

Delete

Problem is how to wrap this within quotes? I have already used both single & double quotes in it.

Right now, the array line looks like this:

```
['39','190507hdyq9o','<a href="http://localhost/cmhs_app/index.php/patient/view/39">DEBI PRASAD CHATTERJEE</a>','66','8670079226',' '<a class="btn-sm btn-danger" href="http://localhost/cmhs_app/index.php/patient/delete/39" onclick="return confirm(\'Do you really want to delete this Patient?\')">Delete</a>'],
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
var arr = ['<a class="btn-sm btn-danger" href="http://localhost/xyz/index.php/item/delete/39" onclick="return confirm(\'Do you really want to delete this Patient?\')">Delete</a>'];

console.log(arr[0]);
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks... My array had one extra ' before the <a> element.